# Seeing failure in cucumber reports but passes in karate report - How do we align these?

Tags: karate

Environment is used here as a simply example, but we have applied the @env=dev flag to restrict this based on env.  In testing a similar feature that should only be tested based on a specific attribute, is it possible to align these somehow, as I am seeing a result difference between the cucumber and karate reports when using the abort() flag to skip subsequent steps.

NOTE:  The abort() function is used, because we simply don't want this test to run in this environment, or if a set attribute, such as account is commercial versus residential, and it is not necessarily a failure.

[image: karate Report]

[image: cucumber Report]

Comment: Instead of marking the steps as passed, can the aborted step be marked as passed and all future steps be marked as skipped?